# How do you POST sign up form data to server URL. Along with redirecting users to a different site such as a thank you page. using javascript or ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms

There are quite a few discussions except I do not have an answer. I am posting a html form to a backend python script. However, I am needing to redirect the users to a thank you page or something. The python script only uses form-data. I also am out of my element with it being ajax or javascript. Here is what I have and would like recommendations.

```
<div class=login-content container" style="max-width: 800px;">
<form role="form" id="form" name="form">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">{{ _("One Last Step") }}</h2>


    <input name="app_name"
        class="form-control" placeholder="{{ _('app_name') }}" required autofocus><br>

    <input name="admin_password"
        class="form-control" placeholder="{{ _('admin_password') }}" required><br>


    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-complete-signup" type="submit" >{{ _("Complete") }}</button>
</form>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $('form').submit(function(){
        $.post('http://website.xyz/api/method/python.script.here', function() {
      window.location.href = "thankyou.html";
    });
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

Any help would be amazing.

Comment: looks like you already did it.... minus posting the data

Comment: You can also post form data using JS, in your example you are not sending any data at all

Comment: Please see how to create a [mcve], particularly how to create a clear problem statement (under "Verifiable")